# what does ":" stands for, in a for function

Tags: java

i have this code, and i would like to know what the ":" mean in the function

```
Element[][] grid = readFile();
for (Element[] ea : grid) {
    for (Element e : ea)
         System.out.print(e.getChar());
     System.out.println();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Java for each loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of a language equivalent, you can think of it as the word "in".  You can read it as "for each Element 'e' in 'ea'".

Here's the documentation on that type of loop: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 1):

When `:` is used in `for`, it acts as a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop. Each iteration, the variable after the colon is assigned to the next value in the array.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
for ( arr : num ) {
    System.out.print( num + " " );
}
// prints "1 2 3 4 "
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a for-each comprehension for Collections and Array. It's same as some languages like Python provide `in` functionality. So when you see a `:` in a `for` loop, read as `in`. For more details see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

In your case it's like `for ea in grid`.

Answer (score 1):

This type of loop is called a 'for-each' loop. The colon (:) is read as 'in'. Basically, this type of for loop is used with collections.

It could be read as:-

```
for each element x in collection Y{
//do something
}
```

Here, in each iteration, the element x refers to the respective elements in Collection Y. i.e, in first iteration, x will be Y[0], in second iteration, x will be y[1], so on and so forth till the end.

The advantage is that condition checking and all those stuff need not be written explicitly. It is especially useful when iteration elements in a collection sequentially till the end. This makes iterating over collections quite easier. It is easier than making use of iterators.

In your code, each element of the two dimensional array 'ea' is printed, using a nested for-each loop. Outer loop iterates over each row (a single dimensional array), and inner loop iterates over each element in the respective row.

Refer these:-
[For-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
[Related question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 0):

This is the new enhanced for loop.

You can read it out loud as for each Element ea in grid.  It iterates over the elements in grid.

Here is a nice [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) .

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a divider between the temporary variable and the `Iterable` **or array**.

 It's called a `foreach` loop, and basically means:

"For each element `ae` in `Iterable` `grid`, do `{...}`"

**Read more here:** [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

`Iterable` being an array or a list, for example.

Comment: The only problem I see is that `grid` isn't an `Iterator`, it's an `Iterable` or array (you cannot use an `Iterator` in a for each loop). But that doesn't deserve a downvote, merely a comment.

Comment: I had it as `Iterable` first, then decided to change it. I always mix those up. :S Cheers though.